# Maven error Android project using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, maven, actionbarsherlock

I am using Maven with the android maven plugin to build my Android project.

I am trying to add a dependency for ActionBarSherlock using Maven.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
  <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

I have specified my pom.xml compiler version to 1.6

```
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
  <source>1.6</source>
  <target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
```

I depend on the correct version of the Android library from Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
  <artifactId>android</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.1.4</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am using API level 16 of Android which is:
- The highest available on Maven central repo
- The version used to build the 4.2.0 version of ActionBarSherlock

A representative portion of the error is here:

```
\target\unpack\apklibs\com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.2.0\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar'.
\target\unpack\apklibs\com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.2.0\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid'.
\target\unpack\apklibs\com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.2.0\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar'.
\target\unpack\apklibs\com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.2.0\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid'.
\target\unpack\apklibs\com.actionbarsherlock_actionbarsherlock_apklib_4.2.0\res\values-v14\abs__styles.xml:12: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse'.
    etc...
```

Comment: Check out the sample applications that come with ABS. They use the Android Maven Plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are declaring the platform version for the android-maven-plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <sdk>
            <platform>16</platform>
        </sdk>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: That should be the solution.